# Splitting a FASTA file - separating ID from species name and outputting a character matrix

Tags: r, bash

I have a FASTA file containing DNA sequences with headers of the form:

```
>EGRPR088-07|Tetrapturus belone
AGTC...
```

and need to split after the | delimiter.

The final output should be a character matrix:

```
          [,1]                 [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
"EGRPR088-07|" "Tetrapturus belone" "A"  "G"  "T"  "C"  ...
```

Using the `ape` package in R, to read in a FASTA file (using `read.FASTA()`) and then converting it via `as.character.DNAbin(as.matrix.DNAbin(x))`, where `x` is the FASTA file, I've managed to get

```
                                  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
EGRPR088-07|Tetrapturus belone    "a"  "g"  "t"  "c"  ...
```

which is close to what I need (conversion of nucleotides to lower case is irrelevant). However, there's no way to access the header.

Am I missing something here? Perhaps this is easier in the terminal? If so, what is the specific bash sequence to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# split the sequence into characters, quote, and print
#
flush() {
    if [[ -n $seq ]]; then
        mapfile -t ary < <(fold -w 1 <<< "$seq" | sed -E 's/(.)/"&"/')
        echo "${ary[*]}"
        seq=                            # clear the seq variable
    fi
}

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line = ">"* ]]; then         # header line
        flush
        echo -n "$line" | sed -E 's/^>([^|]+\|)(.*)/"\1" "\2" /'
    else                                # sequence line(s)
        seq="$seq$line"                 # consider multi-line sequence
    fi
done < file.fasta
flush
```

Example of input fasta file:

```
>EGRPR088-07|Tetrapturus belone
AGTC
AGGC
>EGRPR088-08|Tetrapturus belone
GGAG
AAAT
```

Output:

```
"EGRPR088-07|" "Tetrapturus belone" "A" "G" "T" "C" "A" "G" "G" "C"
"EGRPR088-08|" "Tetrapturus belone" "G" "G" "A" "G" "A" "A" "A" "T"
```

If the fasta file is large, bash script may take a long time to execute. Then please consider other language, such as `perl`:

```
perl -e '
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my @a;
    sub flush {
        if (@a) {
            print(join(" ", map {"\"" . $_ . "\""} @a), "\n");
            @a = ();
        }
    }

    while (<>) {
        chop;
        if (/^>/) {
            flush(@a);
            @a = /^>([^|]+\|)(.*)/;
        } else {
            push(@a, split("", $_));
        }
    }
    flush(@a);
' file.fasta > out.txt
```

**[Edit]**
As the bash script outputs the result on multiple lines of the script, a single
redirection within the script may not work enough.
If you want to redirect the output to a file, put a command:

```
exec > out.txt
```

at the beginning (right after the `#!/bin/bash` line) of the script.
Alternatively, you can save the script file such as `myscript.sh`, then
invoke with:

```
bash myscript.sh > out.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! The bash script works fine since on only have ~11000 sequences. I'd like to output the results to a file. To do this, I just added > out.txt after file.fasta. The file is created, but it is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer with an explanation about the redirection. Hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks so much! Could you also post the edit to the `perl` script? That is, writing results to a file? I now have a file with over 100000 sequences and `bash` is quite slow. Maybe `perl` will be much faster.

Comment: The redirect of the perl version is rather simple. Just add `> out.txt` at the end. I've updated the perl script accordingly. Cheers.

Comment: It seems when I run the script (called `script.pl`) via `perl script.pl` in the terminal, I get an error `Bareword found where operator expected at script.pl line 23, near "' file"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line '' string starting on line 1)
 (Missing operator before file?)
syntax error at script.pl line 1, near "perl -e "
Execution of script.pl aborted due to compilation errors.` However, there are no missing quotes that could be expected to throw this kind of error.

Comment: The script in my posted answer is intended to run with shell something like an awk one-liner which starts with `awk '..'`. You'll see it starts with the `perl` command. Then run it with `bash script.pl`.

Comment: Ah. I see. It's running now.

Comment: Good to hear that.